# how to evaluate the integral without use inverse function or complex numbers

Tags: calculus

$$\int \sqrt{x+2\over x-1}\,dx$$
how to evaluate the integral without use inverse function or complex numbers

Comment: You were given link how to format maths on SE in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761485/how-to-find-a-b-such-that-fx-frac-x42x5ax34x2-bx1-is-contin). Please take time to learn this.

Comment: What does "inverse function" mean while calculating integrals? Can you give an example? Does the answer below satisfy requirements?

Comment: How does one "use inverse functions" to integrate anything? and how can complex numbers help with an antiderivative = an undefined integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use the Substitution $$t=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x-1}}$$ then we get $$x=\frac{t^2+2}{t^2-1}$$ and $$dx=\frac{-6t}{(t^2-1)^2}dt$$
For your Control: a solution is given by $$1/2\,{\frac { \left( x-1 \right)  \left( 2\,\sqrt {{x}^{2}+x-2}+3\,
\ln  \left( 1/2+x+\sqrt {{x}^{2}+x-2} \right)  \right) }{\sqrt {
 \left( x-1 \right)  \left( x+2 \right) }}\sqrt {{\frac {x+2}{x-1}}}}
+C$$